# I Need Help NodeJS Sessions Getting Cleared After Redirecting Pages When Posted On Vercel

Tags: node.js, session, redirect, vercel, supabase

Currently I'm using node.js and Supabase as database also I posted my website in vercel. Now after I logged in succesfully I go to homepage with the data and its working meaning in the studentHomePage i carried the studentData but then after i go to another page it became an internal server error which the sessioned data cant be found. If I used localhost ofcourse it works but in the vercel as posted website not anymore.

GIT: https://github.com/pandimaya/Capstone_SWC_FINAL_VERSION.git

CODE FOR SESSION

```
myapp.use(session({
  secret: 'your_secret_key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false }
}));
```

CODE FOR LOGIN

```
myapp.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const { data, loginError } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email,
      password
    });

    if (loginError) {
      console.error('Error logging in:', loginError.message);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Login failed' });
      return;
    }

    if (!data || !data.user) {
      console.error('Authentication failed');
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Authentication failed' });
      return;
    }
    console.log(data || data.userData);
    
      // Fetch the student data from the specific table
      const { data: studentData, error: studentError } = await supabase
        .from('Student Accounts')
        .select('*')
        .eq('email', email)
        .single();

        // Check if the user is a student
        if (studentData) {
          console.log(studentData);
        // Store the student data in the session
        req.session.studentData = studentData;
        res.status(200).json({ success: 'Login successful', accountType: 'Student' });
        return;
      
    }
    else {
    // Fetch the counselor data from the specific table
    const { data: counselorData, error: counselorError } = await supabase
      .from('Counselor Accounts')
      .select('*')
      .eq('email', email)
      .single();

      // Check if the user is a counselor
    if (counselorData) {
      console.log(counselorData);
      // Store the counselor data in the session
      req.session.counselorData = counselorData;
      // Redirect to the counselor homepage
      res.status(200).json({ success: 'Login successful', accountType: 'Counselor' });
        return;
    }
     else 
     {console.error('User data not found');
     res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }
     
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Unexpected error:', e);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Login failed' });
  }
});
```

CODE FOR PAGE

```
myapp.get('/StudentHomepage', (req, res) => {
  const studentData = req.session.studentData;
  res.render('StudentHomepage', { studentData });
});
```

I don't know what to do anymore since I am new in creating a website.

Comment: For Node.js I'd recommend using Express framework. We have some docs for using Supabase Auth with Node.js Express here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/creating-a-client?framework=express